# How to see or enable full view of the data lineage of Apache NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Apache NiFi 1.6 and I'd like to see the lineage of a flowfile as it passes through different processors.

When I look at the data provenance of a flowfile and look in its "Lineage", I can only see the lineage of the flowfile for that processor, not the ones preceding it. Further, when right clicking the lineage, I only see "view details". I understand there are more options such as "find parents" as shown in the HDF guidelines here: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.1.1/bk_user-guide/content/find-parents.html

Are these options also available in Apache NiFi? If yes, what are your suggestions on how to enable that feature (of being able to see "find parents")?

Comment: could you add to your question the screenshot of your flow (maybe part of it) and lineage that you see...

Answer (score 0):

I found my own mistake. I was trying to find parent by right clicking on anywhere on the lineage. Whereas, it has to be the one with a parent. For example, for my case, it was the first event on top of the page.